# $A=\int_\lambda^\infty \frac{x}{\lambda}e^{-x^2/2}dx, B=\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx$, calculate $\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}A/B$.

Tags: calculus

$$A=\int_\lambda^\infty \frac{x}{\lambda}e^{-x^2/2}dx$$ $$B=\int_\lambda^\infty e^{-x^2/2}dx$$ I want to find: $$\boxed{\lim_{\lambda\to \infty}\frac AB}$$
I think the limit is $1$. But I have some confusions. If I use the L'hopital's rule, can I differentiate w.r.t $\lambda$? I am not sure how to deal with the indefinite integral? Can I treat the $\infty$ as constant？

Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to deal with improper integrals? If so I can write out a hint... if not I'll have to explain more

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$A(\lambda)=\frac1\lambda\int_{\lambda}^\infty x e^{-x^2/2} dx=\frac1\lambda e^{-\frac12\lambda^2}\\
A'(\lambda)=-\frac{1}{\lambda^2}e^{-\frac12\lambda^2}(\lambda^2+1)$$

$$B(\lambda)=\int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-\frac12x^2}dx\\
B'(\lambda)=-e^{-\frac12\lambda^2}$$

$$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{A(\lambda)}{B(\lambda)}=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{A'(\lambda)}{B'(\lambda)}=\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\frac{(\lambda^2+1)}{\lambda^2}\frac{e^{-\frac12\lambda^2}}{e^{-\frac12\lambda^2}}=1$$

Comment: Well done!  Concise, simple, and direct.  +1

Comment: @PaulyB Would you mind taking a look at [my question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436440/correct-calculation-of-recursive-limit)?